# Matplotlib: the x-tick labels I set overlap default labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a boxplot using matplotlib and want to set my own labels for the x-axis using this code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.title("VJV vs SJV", fontsize = 15)
plt.xticks([1, 2], ['VJV', 'SJV'])
plt.boxplot([vjv["amount"], sjv["amount"]])
plt.grid()
plt.show();
```

However, rather than replacing the default axis labels [1,2], it seems that my preferred axis labels ['VJV', 'SJV'] are placed on top of the default axis labels. See image.

[image: Overlapping labels]

How can I remove the default labels and only have my preferred axis labels?

Comment: Where are you running this? (Anyway, it's probably better if you call the xticks after the boxplot).

Comment: jupyter notebook, and yes that solved it - thank you!